# C# method definition is too complicated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, method-declaration

When I looked at the documentation of the EditorFor method from the MVC library I came across this method definition :

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue> {
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    Object additionalViewData
}
```

It felt hard to understand for me but I think HTML helpers can be helpful so I want to understand and I also want to figure out its logic so that I can use it in other method definitions. I would be appreciated if you can help.

Edit: What can be a proper use of this method definition?

Comment: What do/don't you know already? What, specifically, do you need help understanding?

Comment: Do you know about extension methods? That should explain the "this HtmlHelper<TModel> html part of the method.

Comment: How can a method *definition* be too complicated? What is it your don't understand? Or You can [browse the source code for that method if it helps...](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/EditorExtensions.cs)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.pearson-and-steel.co.uk/how-to-use-the-html-editorfor-method/)?

Comment: So i should give it a class as a parameter and then use this class to return an object

Comment: If you want to see some example usages of the method just search for some in Google.  There are plenty out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension method (which is why you see `this` and `static`). It takes two generic types (`<TModel, TValue>`) which you must specify on invoking the method, so that they can then be used/referred to throughout (including the other parameters e.g. `HtmlHelper<TModel>`). This method will return an object of type `MvcHtmlString`.

This is all you can gather from a signature. What it actually does and/or how it does it can only be told from it's contents.

## Reading:

Extension methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx

Generics:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx